# How to print one latest row and previous data of selected column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, inner-join

I am new in php. I have a mysql db. I want to fetch latest record from db and one previous record of selected column. I use INNER Join in my query

```
SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as cname,t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle,s.title as stitle
FROM og_ratings r 
INNER JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
INNER JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
INNER JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
INNER JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
INNER JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
INNER JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
WHERE c.id= 248
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

To print data my php code is

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){


echo '<h1>' .$row["client_id"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["cname"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["ttitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["atitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["otitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["ltitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$row["stitle"]. '</h1>' ;
```

Here i want to display `ltitle` and `stitle` with latest and previous one record

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$last_row = array_pop($row);
echo '<h1>' .$last_row["client_id"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$last_row["cname"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$last_row["ttitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$last_row["atitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$last_row["otitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$last_row["ltitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$last_row["stitle"]. '</h1>' ;

$before_last = array_pop($row);
echo '<h1>' .$before_last["client_id"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$before_last["cname"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$before_last["ttitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$before_last["atitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$before_last["otitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$before_last["ltitle"]. '</h1>' ;
echo '<h1>' .$before_last["stitle"]. '</h1>' ;
```